# IE Edge Displaying IE 9 hack

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

In rendering some SVG images I am using bootstrap .img-responsive class with properties

```
display: block;
width: 100% \9;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

In IE 9 it works as expected by rendering width: 100% property. However IE Edge renders it as width: 100% \9 and make it to not apply properly. Is this a known issue with IE Edge?

Comment: [I'm looking at the source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1119) and I can't find `width` property. Why would you need a hack for it?

Comment: The version I am using is v3.2.0. The issue is without width property IE  does not adhere to max-width given.

Comment: could you bring us sample code to test it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same issue, and seeing that under Edge, some SVGs will display correctly and others will be stretched.

I've opted for a secondary hack on top of the `\9`, care of [Browserhacks](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-d19e53a0fdfba5ec0f283ae86175a3af), which targets IE >= 11:

```
.img-responsive[src$=".svg"] {
  width: 100%\9; /* IE 6-10 */
}
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .img-responsive[src$=".svg"] {
  width: 100%; /* IE 11+ */
}
```

The second selector overrides the `width: 100%\9` (which is considered to be an invalid value in Edge) with a valid `width: 100%`.

I used the CSS3 attribute selector to make these rules only apply to SVGs.  This syntax is supported back to IE 7 (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Further reading:

- https://github.com/4ae9b8/browserhacks/issues/165
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18082